# Unity tile has no transparency

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, transparency, tilesets

My tilemap includes a slanted tile that has transparency, but Unity gives it a background for some reason and I just couldn't figure out how to change that.

[This is how it looks like in the tileset file (opened with GIMP)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13xSW.png)

[Game view (it doesn't work with a background for the game itself either)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPMBT.png)

[How it looks like in the tile palette editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDGk2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself after all! I had to change the tilemap's material. Selected material was [Default-Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPCgc.png), but apparently it needs to be [Sprites-Default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agIbV.png)